# How to store selected information in array?

Tags: perl

I have 1 file to read.

*file1.txt* contains:

```
information1
information2
information3
information4
information5
information6
information7
```

I will write command on the terminal,

```
perl scripts.pl --select information3
```

So the result will take `information3` and before that.
Expected Result

```
information3 
information2
information1
```

if I write the command.

```
perl scripts.pl --select information6
```

Expected result will be:

```
information6
information5
information4
information3
information2
information1
```

My current code:

```
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);;
use Switch;

my $read_file = 'file1.txt';
my $info_name;
my @name;
my $select;

GetOptions( "select|t=s"=> \$select, );

open(READ_FILE,"<", $read_file) || die "Cannot open file $read_file to Read! - $!";

while (<READ_FILE>) {
my $info_name = $_;
if ($info_name =~ m/$select/) {
    $info_name = $_;
    push (@name,($info_name));
    }
}
close(READ_FILE);
print "@name\n";
```

command:

```
perl scripts.pl --select information3
```

result:

```
information3
```

Now I only manage to get what select only.
The result should show:

```
information3 
information2
information1
```

Comment: Since you apparently always want to have everything before the select word and that word itself, then store each item in an array as it is read until you reach the key word -- and then just quit the loop.  LIke `my @items; while (<$fh>) { chomp; push @items, $_; last if /$select/; }`

Comment: Use lexical filehandles, `open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";`. It is much better.

Comment: If you want to name the variable that takes the line -- a good practice -- you can do that inside the condition, `while (my $line = <$fh>) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this code helps to solve your problem.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long qw(GetOptions);

my $select;
my $flag = 0;
my @data;

GetOptions( "select|t=s"=> \$select, );

open (my $fh, '<', "test.txt") or die "Cannot open a file: $!";

while (my $line = <$fh>){
        chomp $line;
        push @data, $line;
        if($line =~ /^$select$/){
                $flag = 1;
                last;
        }
}
close $fh;
if(!$flag){
        print "No match found..\n";
} else {
        print join("\n", reverse @data)."\n";
}
```